# Use an alias as file paths in React native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I keep getting that the file is not found when I'm using the `alias` path.

Example of one of the errors:

> Could not resolve "screens/JobsScreen/JobsListScreen" in file
> D:\Work\heatable-installer-app\heatable-installer-hub\screens\JobsScreen.tsx.

Import:

```
import JobsListScreen from '~/screens/JobsScreen/JobsListScreen';
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          "root": "/",
          "alias": {
            "~/images": "./assets/images",
            "~/fonts": "./assets/fonts",
            "~/navigation": "./navigation",
            "~/hooks": "./hooks",
            "~/screens": "screens/*",
            "~/components": "components"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  };
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "/",
    "paths": {
      "~/images": ["./assets/images/*"],
      "~/fonts": ["./assets/fonts/*"],
      "~/navigation": ["./navigation/*"],
      "~/hooks": ["./hooks/*"],
      "~/screens": ["./screens/*"],
      "~/components": ["./components/*"]
    },  
  },
}
```

Comment: Did you fix the, I'm having the same issue